# Unwanted white space due to image positioned relatively

Tags: html, css

I just want to add a Image and text into the footer but when I do so I get a white space at the bottom of the page I do not know how to get rid of. See http://125.214.65.211:90/specials.php

At the bottom of the page I have added the "Gift Vouchers" image and "Off Street Parking" text.
But this creates the white gap below the pink footer how do I remove the white gap.

I have inherited the website so do not want to change all the existing table structures. I just want some CSS to apply to the existing HTML.

I tried setting the height of the parent  and overflow:hidden but that did not help.

Comment: use firebug because you use unnecessary tr,padding in your footer like you use footer class two times which increasing the height & give padding in .footer .footer2_td

Comment: @sandeep thanks for the tip I was already using firebug and noticed the unnecessary tr,padding and extra footer class/table but they were not the problems, it was a Sotiris answered below, using relative instead of float positioing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This behavior is logic. Using `position:relative` you move the element from it's initial position *but* it still take the space of the initial place with result the white gap. A solution is to remove the relative positioning of image and span, and use floats for the table `.footer`, for the `img` and `float:right` for `span`. For the `.footer` set a width something like `300px` and for `span` a width of `200px`. Also because you have two `.footer` remove the first one which is empty. Then when the elements have their positions you can use `margin` to push them in the correct place, or `position:relative`.

PS: For the next website try to avoid tables for layouts. For more information visit stackoverflow question [Why not use tables for layout in HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/83073/why-not-use-tables-for-layout-in-html)

Comment: Perfect thanks, I knew why the problem was occurring but was not sure how to fix it.   Yes I know to avoid tables, this site was purchased as a template, I am just touching it up

Answer (score 1):

Try to add valign=top for the last  and remove the padding for image , parking text etc.,

that could work, also there is a  with class 'footer2_td', if this is not necessarily needed remove it..